# Give array elements unique IDs

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to multiply every element in an array by the next 12 elements:

```
array.each do |n|
    a = array.index(n)
    b = a + 12
    product = 1
    array[a..b].each { |i| product *= i }
    highest = product if product > highest
end
```

I run into a problem when there are multiple occurrences of the same integer in the array:

`[1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 4, 7] # this is not the actual array`

When the second `7` runs through my block, its `array.index(n)` becomes `3` (the index of the first `7`) when I want it to be `6` (the index of the particular `7` I am working with). I'm pretty sure this can be solved by giving each element of the array a unique 'id', but I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.

My question is, how do I give every element in an array a unique id? The `Array#uniq` method is not what I am looking for.

Comment: They element already has a unique index.  And the largest value has no bearing on its index.  You may want to collect the indexes, and grab the largest index, if that is what you are wanting though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simplify your code a little

```
highest = array.map.with_index do |item, i|
  array[i, 13].inject(:*)
end.max
# printing it console
puts highest
```

or use `array.max_by` with explicit `i` counter

Comment: This is interesting - what is the `#max` doing?

Comment: takes maximum element from array of your products

Comment: And does what with it? How can I save that value to a variable to print to the console?

Answer (score 1):

The index is the uniq id. Use [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) instead:

```
array.each_with_index do |n, a|
  #...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has an `each_cons` [method defined on Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).`each_cons`is short for each_consecutive.

```
array.each_cons(13).max_by{|slice| slice.inject(:*)}
```

For more efficiency consider determining the product of the first thirteen numbers; then going through the array multiplying the product by the next number and dividing it by the previous first, while keeping track of the maximum product.

Comment: It is much more idiomatic Ruby.